# URL params for date select in Node/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime

This is killing me. I am trying to pass to dates to a node route to use as params in a select call. The params are start/end datetimes and trying to query all rows that are between the dates.

This is what I have so far...

Node route:

```
router.get('/dashboarddata/:startdate/:enddate', function(req, res, next) {

    pg.defaults.ssl = true;
    pg.connect('process.env.DATABASE_URL', function(err, client, done) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('db connected');

            client.query('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE datetime BETWEEN ? and ?',[req.params.startdate, req.params.enddate], function(err, result) {
                res.send({ data: result.rows });
                done();
            });

    });

});
```

And I am trying to access it using the following url:

```
www.url.com/dashboarddata/2017-03-03 00:00:00/2017-04-04 00:00:00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you access to your startdate/enddate beofre the pg.connect ?

Comment: Yes I do. I did a res.send(params); to make sure...

Comment: Use console.log to do that

Comment: Can you try that:  function(err, client, done) { ...}.bind(this); (add the .bind(this) to your first callback).

Comment: Still crashes the app.The error in my console >> res.send({ data: result.rows }); TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

Comment: Ah it's simple so, you pg request doesn't send result. You have to test your variables : if(err || !result) res.send('no result :(');

Comment: So youre right. I tried removing err from your if statement and still sent 'no result :(') ... so I am guessing its my url params?

Comment: My data looks like this if I query the whole table...   {"id":61,"lat":"-0.7806859","long":"30.9498006","datetime":"2017-03-28T03:46:38.839Z","satisfaction":"high","idea":"none"},{"id":65,"lat":"-0.7781361","long":"30.9498056","datetime":"2017-03-28T10:18:10.125Z","satisfaction":"high","idea":"none"},    Am I using the wrong format for my url params?

Comment: Just wondering if anyone else may have any input into this?